# RecyclerView Attempt to invoke virtual method

Tags: android, android-fragment, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Добрый день. Сразу скажу, я новичок.

у меня есть необходимость создать приложение на Android с активностью и тремя фрагментами, на одном из которых список с RecyclerView и CardView  `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.setLayoutManager(android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager)' on a null object reference
                                                                               at com.khachaturyan.contacts.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)`

прикрепляю код

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.khachaturyan.contacts;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.Action;
import com.google.android.gms.appindexing.AppIndex;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.khachaturyan.contacts.fragments.FragmentADD;
import com.khachaturyan.contacts.fragments.FragmentDELETE;
import com.khachaturyan.contacts.fragments.FragmentImport;

import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    Preferences data;
    MyAdapter adapter;
    FragmentImport impgallery;
    FragmentADD addgallery;
    FragmentDELETE delgallery;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
    private GoogleApiClient client;
RecyclerView recyclerView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        data = new Preferences(this);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager  layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        List<Workers> workers = data.getWorkers();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(workers, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               /* android.app.FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                ftrans.replace(R.id.container, addgallery);
                ftrans.commit();*/


                                                data.addWorker(WorkerGenerator.generateWorker());
                                                adapter.dataSetChanged(data.getWorkers());
                                                recyclerView.scrollToPosition(data.getWorkers().size() - 1);



                // Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


        impgallery = new FragmentImport(); //инициализация объектов
        addgallery = new FragmentADD();
        delgallery = new FragmentDELETE();
        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction ftrans = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, impgallery); /*В созданном пакете fragments открываете код каждого фрагмента (например FragmentGallery.java) и исправляете в наследовании "extends Fragment" "на extends android.app.Fragment"*/
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, addgallery);


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            ftrans.replace(R.id.container, delgallery);

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        } ftrans.commit();

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        client.connect();
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.khachaturyan.contacts/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.start(client, viewAction);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
        // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
        Action viewAction = Action.newAction(
                Action.TYPE_VIEW, // TODO: choose an action type.
                "Main Page", // TODO: Define a title for the content shown.
                // TODO: If you have web page content that matches this app activity's content,
                // make sure this auto-generated web page URL is correct.
                // Otherwise, set the URL to null.
                Uri.parse("http://host/path"),
                // TODO: Make sure this auto-generated app URL is correct.
                Uri.parse("android-app://com.khachaturyan.contacts/http/host/path")
        );
        AppIndex.AppIndexApi.end(client, viewAction);
        client.disconnect();
    }
}
```

**MyAdapter.java**

```
package com.khachaturyan.contacts;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

/**
 * Created by mkmtst on 25.10.2017.
 */
public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<Workers> workersList = new ArrayList<>();
Context ctx;
    public MyAdapter(List<Workers> workers, Context ctx) {


        workersList = workers;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
    }
    public void dataSetChanged(List<Workers> kontaktyList) {
        this.workersList = workersList;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_main, parent, false);     //
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) { //выполняется для каждого айтема и передает данные в layout
        holder.name.setText(workersList.get(position).getName());
        holder.age.setText("Age: " + workersList.get(position).getAge());
        holder.position.setText("Номер: " + workersList.get(position).getNomer());
        Glide.with(ctx).load(workersList.get(position).getPhoto())
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .into(holder.photo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() { //возвращает количество элементов
        return workersList.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
TextView name;
        TextView age;
        TextView position;
        CircleImageView photo;
        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            age = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.age);
            position = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.position);
            photo = (CircleImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.photo);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс **Workers.java** с данными

```
public class Workers {
    private int id;
   private      String name;
    private     Integer photo;
    private     String age;
    private String position;
    private  String nomer;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getPhoto() {
        return photo;
    }

    public void setPhoto(Integer photo) {
        this.photo = photo;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public String getNomer() {
        return nomer;
    }

    public void setNomer(String nomer) {
        this.nomer = nomer;
    }
}
```

Класс **WorkerGenerator.java** для генерации рандомных персонажей

```
public class WorkerGenerator {
    private static List<String> maleNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("John", "Bill", "Bob", "Oliver", "Jack", "Harry", "George", "William", "Henry"));
    private static List<String> femaleNames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Anna", "Emma", "Sophie", "Jessica", "Scarlett", "Molly", "Lucy", "Megan"));
    private static List<String> surnames = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Green", "Smith", "Taylor", "Brown", "Wilson", "Walker", "White", "Jackson", "Wood"));
    private static List<Integer> femalePhoto = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.f1 , R.drawable.f2, R.drawable.f3 , R.drawable.f4, R.drawable.f5 , R.drawable.f6, R.drawable.f7));
    private static List<Integer> malePhoto = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(R.drawable.m1 , R.drawable.m2, R.drawable.m3 , R.drawable.m4, R.drawable.m5 , R.drawable.m6));
    private static List<String> positions = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Android programmer", "iOs programmer", "Web programmer", "Designer"));
    public static Workers generateWorker(){
        Workers workers = new Workers();
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();
        int index = randomGenerator.nextInt(2);
        if (index == 0) {
            index = randomGenerator.nextInt(maleNames.size());
            String randomName = maleNames.get(index);
            index = randomGenerator.nextInt(surnames.size());
            String randomSurname = surnames.get(index);
            workers.setName(randomName + " " + randomSurname);
            index = randomGenerator.nextInt(malePhoto.size());
            Integer randomPhoto = malePhoto.get(index);
            workers.setPhoto(randomPhoto);
        } else {
            index = randomGenerator.nextInt(femaleNames.size());
            String randomName = femaleNames.get(index);
            index = randomGenerator.nextInt(surnames.size());
            String randomSurname = surnames.get(index);
            workers.setName(randomName + " " + randomSurname);
            index = randomGenerator.nextInt(femalePhoto.size());
            Integer randomPhoto = femalePhoto.get(index);
            workers.setPhoto(randomPhoto);
        }
        workers.setAge(Integer.toString(21 + randomGenerator.nextInt(6)));
        index = randomGenerator.nextInt(positions.size());
        workers.setPosition(positions.get(index));
        return workers;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это значит, что в activity_main.xml нет элемента с id `recycler_view`

Answer (score 2):

В логах всё есть, у вас NullPointerException инициирован методом .setLayoutManager на строке кода 53 в классе MainActivity в методе (колбеке) onCreate.
Чаще всего такая ошибка:

1.Забыли указать новый id.

2.Забыли сменить новую разметку в методе setContentView

3.Нет такого элемента с таким id в размекте.

Также бывает, что после смены id необходимо подчистить кеш, для этого попробуйте сделать CLean and Rebuild в AS во вкладке Build.